# How can I call an executable to run on a separate machine within a program on my own machine (win xp)?

Tags: expect, multiple-languages, grid-computing

My objective is to write a program which will call another executable on a separate computer(all with win xp) with parameters determined at run-time, then repeat for several more computers, and then collect the results.  In short, I'm working on a grid-computing project.  The algorithm itself being used is already coded in FORTRAN, but we are looking for an efficient way to run it on many computers at once.

I suppose one way to accomplish this would be to upload a script to each computer and then run said script on each computer, all automatically and dependent on my own parameters.  But how can I write a program which will write to, upload, and run a script on a separate computer?

I had considered GridGain, but the algorithm is already coded and in a different language, so that is ruled out.

My current guess at accomplishing this task is using Expect ([wiki/Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)), but I have no knowledge of the tool.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PsExec for this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

You could also look at the open source alternative RemCom:

http://rce.sourceforge.net/

It's actually pretty simple to write your own as well but RCE will show you how to do it if you want. Although, using PsExec may just suffice your needs.

Comment: Very interesting.  I like this, and unfortunately it's not that simple for me.  Would it be easier for me to add a features to this program, or write a program which manipulates remcom?  If so, any clues as to how?

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do would be to use PsExec and in your program execute PsExec with the appropriate arguments to run the remote executable.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into [PVM](http://www.csm.ornl.gov/pvm/pvm_home.html), it was made for the type of situation you're describing, but you may have to annotate your existing codebase and/or implement a wrapper application.